# C# WP8 Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaQueue

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the currently playing song on windows phone.

To do this, I did

```
MediaQueue s = s.ActiveSong;
```

For some reason, I get the above error when doing this. Probably a simple mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems as though `MediaQueue s` is of the type `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaQueue` and `s.ActiveSong` is of the type `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song`.

I think you are looking to do

```
Song s = mediaQueue.ActiveSong;
```

where `mediaQueue` is an instance of `MediaQueue`.